# seperate full name into first name and last name MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I started my first year of learnig software development and there is a question I just can't solve, and sadly because of the corona virus I can't ask a teacher util next week.
I have a table with full names and I need to separate them into a first name and a last name
I have found some solutions that use `SUBSTRING_INDEX` but I haven't red about it anywhere yet.
I somehow found a way to get the last name, but I just can't get the first name done.
This is how I did the last name:

```
SELECT RIGHT(name, LENGTH(name) - INSTR(name, " ")) AS lastname FROM student;
```

Is there anybody that can help me with this?
Thanks in advance

Comment: To get the  first name is easier than the last name. It is the part of the full name up to the space (' ').

Answer (score 2):

Use `substring_index()`:

```
select substring_index(name, ' ', 1) as first_name,
       substring_index(name, ' ', -1) as last_name
```

This assumes that the name has only two parts.

Answer (score 0):

Use [SUBSTRING_INDEX](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) to get everything at the left of the first space as one value, and everything past the first space as other value:

```
SELECT substring_index(name, ' ', 1) AS firstname,
       substring_index(name, ' ', -1) AS lastname
```